# Composer fails to self-update

Tags: php, composer-php

When I try to run composer self-update, I get the error:

```
The file is corrupted (creating archive "/home/heytherejake/.composer/cache/composer-temp.phar" disabled by the php.ini setting phar.readonly).
Please re-run the self-update command to try again.
```

I have set phar.readonly set to Off (and my phpinfo reflects this), yet the error still occurs. Does anyone know what else might cause this?

Comment: Possibly try something like `rm -rf ~/.composer/cache/*` (run at your own risk, but don't see how it could hurt).  Or completely re-install Composer manually?

Comment: Attempting to reinstall Composer gives the same error, unfortunately. (different location, though: The download is corrupt (creating archive "/etc/php5/apache2/composer.phar" disabled by the php.ini setting phar.readonly), aborting.)

Comment: Interesting..what method do you install it with?  Even though I don't recommend this, I'm curious to know if it works installing as superuser.

Comment: Well, in my attempts to fix it I asssumed it might be a permissions error, and accidentally changed my /etc/ permissions recursively to 755, and now I can't sudo. Gimme a sec...

Comment: Run `php -i` on the command line and double check if you correctly enabled .phar writing. Note that there usually are TWO configuration files, one for the webserver, and one for the command line. Composer uses the command line configuration if you run it on the command line.

Comment: That fixed that issue, but now I'm getting   [ErrorException]                                                             
  rename(/home/heytherejake/.composer/cache/composer-temp.phar,/usr/local/bin  
  /composer): Permission denied

Edit: Nevermind, sudoing worked. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it so it doesn't do the check in case phar.readonly is enabled now, see https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/3251f9f1aa997479fff78905841e22beacfbe37b

Comment: You might want to offer the fix for your questions as an answer and accept it; that way other users running into this will have a clear answer for this question.

Answer (score 11):

The best solution is to remove composer and then reinstall it:

i. Find Composer:

```
which composer
```

ii. Then remove it as sudo (use the directory returned from above)

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/composer
sudo rm -rf ~/.composer/cache/
```

iii. Then install it using apt-get

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install curl php5-cli git
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

iv. Then test if it's working

```
composer self-update
```

Answer (score 10):

Composer not updating or working properly is usually due to one of two things. Bad permission and/or bad cache.

To Remove cache, use `sudo rm -rf ~/.composer/cache/`

To fix permission issue change composer.phar permission to 755:

```
which composer
sudo chmod 755 path/to/composer
```

as a last mean of fixing this issue, try to update with sudo `sudo -H composer self-update`

Comment: NEVER do `chmod 777`, please!

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai Thx for tip, but could you elaborate and give me a correction so that i can update my post ?

Comment: @NMC check out the answer from Paulo Pereira

Answer (score -1):

just write that in your terminal

-sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-
  dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer